Enderton Set Theory Question on Cardinals and Ordinals
Assume that A is a set and define (as in Hartogs' theorem) α to be the set of ordinals dominated by A. Show that (i) a is a cardinal number, (ii) card A<α, and (iii) α is the least cardinal greater than card A.
Text Book Question Image
Hi all, I was wondering how I should approach the third part of this question?
I'm just beginning to learn about ordinals and cardinals in my set theory class, so I want to make sure my understanding is appropriate.

Let us suppose for that sake of contradiction that exists a cardinal $\beta$ greater than card(A) and less than $\alpha$ such that card(A) < $\beta$ < $\alpha$.
Well, since $\alpha$ is an ordinal as a corollary by Hartog's Theorem, so any ordinal less than $\alpha$ is a member of it.
Recall that any member in $\alpha$ is injectable into A by Hartog's construction. Thus, we have that $\beta$ is injectable into A, and at the same time A is injectable into $\beta$ (since card(A) < $\beta$). This would imply A is equinumerous with $\beta$ (I think this is by Bernstein theorem or something I can't recall unfortunately).
But again card(A) < $\beta$. Thus, card(A) is a proper subset of $\beta$ since  they're both ordinals.
Now we reach the contradiction that a set is equinumerous with a proper subset of itself. So $\beta$ can't exist.

I think my approach is somewhat in the correct direction, but as I'm new to everything here I'm not exactly sure what to assume and what not to assume, what theorems are appropriate to apply, etc.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!! Thank you!!!

Your approach looks on the right track from steps 1-3, but 4 and 5 go off the rails. In number 5, you say there is a contradiction from a set being equinumerous with a proper subset of itself, but that's wrong. Any infinite set is equinumerous with a proper subset of itself... that's one definition of being infinite (this requires a weak form of the axiom of choice, but this problem is clearly assuming AC).
There's nothing incorrect in your statement in 4, but you don't need it. You are already done in step 3. You have that $A$ is equinumerous with $\beta,$ i.e. $|A|=\beta,$ but that's a contradiction with the supposition that $|A|<\beta.$

For the big picture here it's useful to observe and internalize:

The definitions tell us $\beta<\alpha$ if and only if $|\beta|\le |A|.$

Then there are very quick arguments for all 3 parts:

(i) If there were a $\beta<\alpha$ with $|\beta|=|\alpha|$, we'd have $|\alpha| = |\beta|\le |A|,$ so we'd have $\alpha < \alpha$... contradiction.
(ii) If $|A|\ge \alpha,$ then $|\alpha|\le |A|,$ so again $\alpha < \alpha$... contradiction. So by cardinal trichotomy, $|A| < \alpha.$
(iii) Immediate from (ii) and the above observation: any lesser cardinal $\beta < \alpha$ has $\beta = |\beta|\le |A|.$


Thank you! I got it!
